# GMock EXPECT_CALL doesn't match AnyMatcher

Tags: c++, tdd, googletest, googlemock

**Code:**

```
class MockDefault : public Verifyingcalls::DefaultSCI_OCB {
    public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(op, void());
    MOCK_METHOD1(op1, void(sc_integer param1));
    MOCK_METHOD2(op2, void(sc_boolean param1, sc_integer param2));
};

TEST_F(VerifyCallCount, after3Cycle) {
    MockDefault defaultMock;

    EXPECT_CALL(defaultMock, op1(_)).Times(AtLeast(4));

    EXPECT_CALL(defaultMock, op2(_,_)).Times(AtLeast(4));

    EXPECT_CALL(defaultMock, op1(5l)).Times(AtLeast(2));

    EXPECT_CALL(defaultMock, op1(7l)).Times(AtLeast(2));

    EXPECT_CALL(defaultMock, op2(true, 7l)).Times(AtLeast(2));

    EXPECT_CALL(defaultMock, op2(true, 5l)).Times(AtLeast(2));
...
}
```

I have a problem or at least an unexpected behavior when running this test:
If I comment out the specific `EXPECT_CALL's` the test works just fine but if I don't i get this Failure:

**Error:**

```
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(defaultMock, op2(_,_))...
         Expected: to be called at least 4 times
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
..\gtests\VerifyCallCount\VerifyCallCount.cc:123: Failure
```

**Question:**

My question is, why does the test fail?
I would assume that the function `op1` was called at least 4 times, at least two times with the argument 5 and two times with the argument 7. So why did the test fail?

Comment: What are the values op2 is called with?

Comment: two times with `(true, 7L)` and two times with `(true, 5L)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in this case the expectations

```
EXPECT_CALL(defaultMock, op2(true, 7l)).Times(AtLeast(2));
EXPECT_CALL(defaultMock, op2(true, 5l)).Times(AtLeast(2));
```

are called and

```
EXPECT_CALL(defaultMock, op2(_,_)).Times(AtLeast(4));
```

is not called, because the two others match. With `gmock` only one match is executed not all matches. An `EXPECT_CALL` can for example return values. That would not be unique if more than one match is called.